# defface with less redundancy

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to define a bunch of faces for different characters like below:

```
(defface char-face-a
  '((((type tty) (class color)) (:background "yellow" :foreground "black"))
    (((type tty) (class mono)) (:inverse-video t))
    (((class color) (background dark)) (:background "yellow" :foreground "black"))
    (((class color) (background light)) (:background "yellow" :foreground "black"))
    (t (:background "gray")))
  "Face for marking up A's"
  :group 'char-faces)

(defface char-face-b
  '((((type tty) (class color)) (:background "red" :foreground "black"))
    (((type tty) (class mono)) (:inverse-video t))
    (((class color) (background dark)) (:background "red" :foreground "black"))
    (((class color) (background light)) (:background "red" :foreground "black"))
    (t (:background "gray")))
  "Face for marking up B's"
  :group 'char-faces)

...
...
```

Is there anyway to avoid explicitly write all the `defface` definitions and make the code less redundant? (I know `make-face`, but it seems deprecated and can't set attributes according to different terminal types as `defface` does.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a macro and a loop that operates on a mapping of suffixes <-> colors:

```lisp
(defmacro brian-def-char-face (letter backgrnd foregrnd)
  `(defface ,(intern (concat "brian-char-face-"
                 letter))
     '((((type tty) (class color)) 
        (:background 
     ,backgrnd
     :foreground
     ,foregrnd))
       (((type tty) (class color)) (:inverse-video t))
       (((class color) (background dark))
    (:foreground
     ,foregrnd
     :background
     ,backgrnd))
       (((class color) (background light))
    (:foreground
     ,foregrnd
     :background
     ,backgrnd))
       (t (:background "gray")))
     ,(concat "Face for marking up " (upcase letter) "'s")))

(let ((letcol-alist '((s . (white black))
              (t . (black yellow))
              (u . (green pink)))))
  (loop for elem in letcol-alist
    for l = (format "%s" (car elem))
    for back = (format "%s" (cadr elem))
    for fore = (format "%s" (caddr elem))
    do 
    (eval (macroexpand `(brian-def-char-face ,l ,back ,fore)))))
```

Gives you new faces:

`brian-char-face-s`, `brian-char-face-t`, and `brian-char-face-u`

Now you just need to maintain the list of letter<->color mappings, and possibly extend the macro to support other face properties (if desired).

Answer (score 5):

1. `make-face` is not at all deprecated, AFAICT.
2. `defface` can make use of inheritance -- see face attribute `:inherit`.
   Dunno whether that helps in your particular context.

Comment: +1. I would define a base face for all your faces that contains all the common attributes, and then inherit all your other faces from it.

Comment: +1. I saw this in the help info:`(make-face FACE &optional NO-INIT-FROM-RESOURCES)

Define a new face with name FACE, a symbol.
Do not call this directly from Lisp code; use defface instead.` that's why I thought it was deprecated

Comment: Interesting, what Emacs version are you using? I don't see that last sentence (about not using it in Lisp code) as part of the help in any Emacs version I have, from Emacs 20 to an Emacs 24 build from yesterday.